# JQuery Mobile theme roller theme won't apply on iPhone or iPAD

Tags: jquery, iphone, ipad, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-themeroller

I created a custom theme for my ASP.Net MVC 4 web application using JQuery Mobile themeroller.  I downloaded the theme and overwrote the default theme with the custom theme using the same file names.  When I test the app on a PC web browser I see the new theme, but when I test on an iPhone or iPAD, I see the default theme.  Why doesn't the custom color theme work on the actual devices?

Comment: The same thing happens on an Android tablet.  Why would the PC browser show the colors correctly but the mobile device browsers show the colors incorrectly when both are pointing to the same web site?

Comment: Edit:  As a test I cleared the cache on the Safari browser on the iPhone and tested again.  The issue still happens if I run the app from the home page web app icon, however if I navigate to it using the Safari browser (not using the web app icon) then it shows the correct colors.  Is this some kind of a bug in Safari when it is in Standalone mode?

Comment: Edit:  After clearing the Safari browser cache on the iPAD it is now showing the correct colors there, but on the iPhone it still refuses to if the browser is launched in standalone mode.  Can someone help with this?  Custom themes become useless if the web app will not display them.

Comment: I read that someone else had a similar issue and he had to actually reboot the iPhone device for it to show the correct theme colors.  I tried that on my iPhone 4 and still no go.  It refuses to use the custom theme colors.